# Универсальная библиотека компонентов Vue 2 / Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет!

Надо сделать либу компонентов для проекта на вуе 2 (без TS).  Какой стек посоветуете для этого?
Надо в том числе и компоненты графиков оборачивать (echarts).

- Предвижу, что в будущем понадобится обновляться до вуе 3, поэтому думаю об универсальном подходе.

Нагуглил :  vue-demi.
Вот пример на нем: https://github.com/alvarosaburido/vue-universal-lib-example

Но автор предупреждает, что это костыльный вариант в начале и в конце: https://alvarosaburido.dev/blog/how-to-create-an-universal-library-for-vue-2-3

- я вообще не смог установить его либу в вуе 2. Rollup в папку DIST складывает. В npm  - локальный файл в dist.
  Затем ставлю как плагин, Vue.use, но никак не удалось...
  Вообще, было бы удобно отдельно импортировать каждый компонент...

Больше всего понравился этот, но он ток на вуе 3:  тут все идеально.
https://github.com/ulissesferreira/moon
МБ имеет смысл попытаться его адаптировать и под вуе 2 ? НО там vite билдит либу компонентов.

---

У кого был подобный опыт, что скажете?
———
В общем, вопросов много. Интересно, где люди берут подобные сведения? И где мне их брать?

Comment: Однако, перед тем как браться за подобные комплексные задачи, надо бы базовым вещам научиться: например, что такое именованные экспорты (в стандартных ESM прежде всего), как пользоваться бандлерами для сборки библиотек, и как корректно транслитерировать "Vue" :)

Comment: По сути ведь именно в экспорты все упирается: полностью прозрачную совместимость 2.* и 3.* не получится реализовать просто из-за различий в API (с которыми можно ознакомиться в оф. руководстве по миграции). Так что придется делать варианты под оба прогр. интерфейса, если хочется 2.* поддерживать. Ну а относительно чисто технического момента сборки - Rollup стал де-факто стандартом для библиотек, так что имеет смысл обратить внимание на него в первую очередь. Vite тоже его использует. Если не нравятся болячки Vite, то для dev-процесса можно и Snowpack взять (он тоже быстр и легок в обращении).

Comment: @yar85 , а что про vue-demi скажешь?

Comment: I found an example - https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-vue
What do u think about this?

Comment: @yar85 писать комопненты на Vue2, c тем прицелом, что они будут использоваться во Vue3 - вполне реально. + в особо  сложных случаях, можно использовать `webpack-conditional-loader`.

Comment: _«а что про vue-demi скажешь?»_ - ничего, т.к. стараюсь избегать подобных вещей (предпочитая добавлять зависимости только когда они реально требуются, и не прогибаться под чужие решения в адекватности которых не уверен). Да, подобные инструменты могут быть для кого-то единственным путем решения, но остальным-то зачем зависеть от сомнительной реализации того что они сами могут сделать - потому что готовое модно? А какой тогда смысл изучать технологию, если не пользоваться возможностями которые открывает знание? Может я чего-то не понимаю, конечно... :)

Comment: @Дмытрык, можно и реально, но вебпак для разработки библиотек так себе бандлер. Он все-таки для SPA или лэндингов гораздо лучше подходит. А в последнее время начинаю и для последних роллап юзать, т.к. многие привычные лоадеры и плагины плохо работают с пятой версией вебпака, а новый встроенный ассет-менеджмент откровенно унылый (толком не конфигурируется, да еще и глючит).

Comment: @Дмытрык, еще 11ty очень многообещающий проект - это SSG, а не бандлер, но статичные сайтики со скриптами, для которых SPA оверкилл, с ним делать очень-очень приятно. Практически все популярные шаблонизаторы поддерживаются искаропки, любой сборщик (для sass и транспайла JS) подключается без проблем, и есть потрясающе гибкий API для написания собственных плагинов/шорткодов. Как альтернативу вебпаку+HtmlWebpackPlugin (и особенно для MPA) очень рекомендую.

Comment: @kostia7alania, глянул исходники vue-demi, в целом годно. Немножко скривило от того как код организован (типа "DRY? не, не слышал"), но в остальном выглядит более-менее прилично. Принцип предельно простой (проброс импортов к составляющим вью3, по сути... что-то типа полифилла), поэтому скорее всего будет надежно - если в фактическом использовании не вылезет граблей от мелких несовместимостей, то вполне сойдет эта библиотечка, когда пофиг на эффективность и лениво самому адаптировать свой код под апи вью2. Все-таки я за то чтобы делать красиво, отдельные экспорты под 2.*, но не буду настаивать)

Comment: @yar85, решил, что буду экспортить гит-модулем. Слишком долго в этих всех штуках разбираться, бизнес не ждет

Comment: @yar85, кстати, нашел либу по генерации конфигов 
https://nicedoc.io/team-innovation/vue-sfc-rollup#user-content-install